# Azure Devops Git history tree view - tree not connected?

Tags: git, azure-devops

After merging a pull request, the tree view looks like this:

[image]

This looks like the commit `190abbec` is not connected to the earlier history of the git tree.

I spent more time than I should have trying to understand what was happening here, so I am posting this question along with the answer in case someone else encounters the same phenomenon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the connections are far apart, the tree view in Azure DevOps does not desplay the link by default.

If you merge changes in master to your local branch more often, this will not happen.

In order to see the connection simply click the arrow to expand:

[image]